# How to track all changes inside a SharePoint site

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

I would like to know whether there is any API to get all changes inside a SharePoint site. I've done research in SharePoint. But I found out that changes API retrieves changes inside a list. I would like to get relative URLs or unique IDs of files changed inside a SharePoint site with or without supplying a change token.

Answer (score 1):

- Enable Audit logging from Central Administration
- Configure Site collection audit settings from Site settings
- View audit log reports from Site settings

Check this post which lets you in detailed how to track changes on SharePoint Server:
https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/126012-how-to-track-changes-on-sharepoint-server-2013

Configure audit settings in SharePoint which lets you track user actions on a sites content types, lists, libraries, list items, and library files within your site collections: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configure-audit-settings-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Click the 3 dots on the right of any file/folder within the sharepoint site and select Alert me, this will give you updates whenever the file/folder is edited/moved/changed/deleted etc.